# Is it possible to interconvert between numpy array and list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

You can convert a numpy array to a list like so:

```
a = np.array([x,y,z,...])
b = a.tolist()
```

I could convert back by defining a new array:

```
c = np.array(b)
```

Is it possible to do this conversion without creating a new array/list? So that it would give the following non-existent functionality:

```
a = np.array([x,y,z,...])
a.tolist()
a.np.array()
```

Essentially I have a for loop in which I do some maths with numpy arrays to determine which element to remove. But then I have to do the next iteration without that element. I need the list mutability for something like this:

```
values.tolist()
values.pop(start_size + i)
values=np.array(values)
```

Or to be able to do something like this (which again, doesn't work):

```
new_array = np.delete(values, start_size + i)
values = new_array
```

Comment: Nope.  The 2 operations produce new objects each time.  The underlying data structures are too different.

Comment: It may help if you expanded on the kinds of calculations that you need to do.  There may be ways of 'deleting' elements without actually deleting.  Even with a list, 'pop' in the middle isn't cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.r_` to create a nifty slice to accomplish the `pop`

```
values = np.arange(5)
i = 2

popped = values[i]
values = values[np.r_[0:i, i+1:values.size]]


print(values, popped)

[0 1 3 4] 2
```

Comment: This still creates new array objects every time a value is popped.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a list which is just like an array, as @hpaulj already mentioned. From your description of your problem, it appears as though you may be able to use masked arrays for the same effect. Here's a small example where I successively remove the smallest element from an array:

```
import numpy
import numpy.ma

a = numpy.ma.array([5, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6])
for i in range(3):
    minelement = numpy.argmin(a)
    a[minelement] = numpy.ma.masked
output = a.compressed()
```

Comment: I've never used masked arrays before (beginner here). Would you be able to feed the length of the new array into the for loop upper bound? I'm iteratively removing outlying data. So every time I remove an outlying data point, I have to apply the loop over the new array.

Comment: The length of the array stays fixed, it's just that some elements are marked as invalid and don't participate in `numpy` operations as shown in my example. If you're removing outliers, don't you keep removing until some stopping condition is true?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a work around to the application in the question, that is deleting an element from an array and defining an array with the same name.

e.g. removing 2 from a

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
b = a[0:2]
c = a[3:]
a = np.append(b,c)
```

Unfortunately, I've run into the larger problem that updating the array "values" at the end of the loop will not change the last value of i in the loop, which is a function of len(values)... I get an error.

Comment: You will save yourself and us a lot of time by thinking about what the actual problem is you're trying to solve and then describing that in a new question. You've now hit two x problems on the way to the y problem: http://xyproblem.info/. The best questions start with the big top level problem "I'm trying to remove successive outliers" and then asks about the intermediate issue "The loop runs up to len(values) but I make values smaller".